# PHP decimal position of math result

Tags: php, decimal, rounding

If variable A = 0.07 when echoed
and variable B = 2100.00 when echoed

if we:   **$c = $a * $b;**

when the end result is a whole # ( i.e.  $c = 147) is there any way to force the
result to keep 2 decimal places and hold the trailing zero's so that ( $c = 147.00 ) ??

I have tried the following but the result still reported a whole number without trailing zero's:

```
$c = round($c,2);
```

So what obvious thing am i missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at PHP's [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)() function. You could do:

```
$cStr = number_format($c, 2);
```

to get a string with two decimal points. Note that the result of number_format() is a `string`, not a number

Comment: Or `printf("%.2f", $number)` (might be more convenient if you're just going to print it anyway)

Comment: Well this does work but you said the result is a string and not a number. This is all pre-processing in a e-cart before being transmitted to a payment gateway. Passing the result to the gateway as a string vs a number shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: How are you passing this to the gateway?

Comment: It will pass to gateway as a $_POST value, i was testing what you had and it won't work that way. The result of the code below is 2 when it should be 2000.00. I cant pass that to the payment gateway as it would be wrong $2 vs $2000: `$a=1000.00;
$b=1000.00;
$a = number_format($a,2);
$b = number_format($b,2);
echo $a;
echo "<br>";
echo $b;
$c = $a+$b;
echo "<br>".$c;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format a number as a string, you should use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
$c_string = number_format($c, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to force the *variable* to have 2 decimal positions. You can use `number_format()` to force on *display* though.